# Managing code editors and its code from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio

I created a web server which can run code for 4 web apps being developed, based on Ubuntu 20.04. At first, Github was going to be the way to go for handling code between the coders, as it can be synced with our environment (Visual Studio Code in this case) but we want to store code directly in the server instead of dealing with Github repositories because of security concerns and easiness to upload from test to production. Is there a way of creating a shared repository which can be later synced using VS Code? The objective is having a shared environment, being able to see from VS the code others developed without having to resync again the whole repository.

Comment: You could go with a self-hosted solution if security is the concern. Want to give the gitlab a try? Gogs is another popular self-hosted git solution, the internet says.

Answer (score 1):

> At first, Github was going to be the way to go for handling code between the coders, as it can be synced with our environment (Visual Studio Code in this case) but we want to store code directly in the server instead of dealing with Github repositories because of security concerns and easiness to upload from test to production.

No, you don't. What you want to do is to learn the tools:

- Use proper [secret management tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_management)
- [Automate things](https://github.com/features/actions)
- Use different branches, e.g. `development`, `prod`, `testing` and so forth to separate things. An *automated* workflow may be development -> testing -> prod, with each step automated when the pull request is signed off.

This involves learning how to work with both git and Github (or any other git platform, such as Gitlab or Azure Devops).

Comment: in that case, I guess we will continue to work with Github. It is the syncing what we are missing in this case. We do have the repos and the server running as web, but how can we create a link between the repo and the actual source of the web service (/var/www/)?

Comment: You can automate it [using a hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). Or you can set up a [remote origin](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa) and push to the web server. The tools is more or less made for your use case, but you have to figure out the finer details of how you want to do it.